# How to place marker/ plot Longitude and latitude on android google map v2

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, google-maps-android-api-2

I have successfully displayed android google map v2 on my application, my problem right now is how to place marker or plot my longitude and latitude on the map. I found tutorials on the internet but I can't find ways to used it because all of those were using java. I am using C# in android programming, can you show me any sample codes using c# on placing marker/plotting longitude and latitude on android google map v2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin's [MapsAndLocationDemo_v3](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/MapsAndLocationDemo_v3/) sample has examples of [placing markers](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/MapsAndLocationDemo_v3/SimpleMapDemo/MapWithMarkersActivity.cs#L78).

Answer (score 1):

```
LatLng myLoc = new LatLng(latitude, longitue);
BitmapDescriptor bitmapDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE);
GoogleMap googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myLoc)
            .icon(bitmapDescriptor).title(myLoc.toString()));
```

Comment: your code works, I have plotted many longlats on my map, now I want to connect those markers. How could I do that?